# Android - drag and resize, error when pinch touch out of bounds

Tags: android, view, touch, zooming, drag

I am attempting to implement the dragging and resizing of a View Object. I was having problems with the pinch zoom gesture in that sometimes when the fingers moved apart too fast and left the View Object that had the touch listener attached to it (same View Object I'm trying to drag and scale), the app would crash.

So instead I attached the touch listener to a View which fills the screen and then I just restrict touch actions depending on the location of the touch events. E.g. if the touch even is in the bounds of the target object, then it can be dragged, and if I am touching outside of its bounds, then it cant be dragged.

Below is the code for the touch listener attached to the entire screen.

```
scaleView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            float viewWidth = mTouchBox.getWidth();
            float viewHeight = mTouchBox.getHeight();
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mode = DRAG;
                //get initial box coords:
                x_0 = mTouchBox.getX();
                y_0 = mTouchBox.getY();
                //get initial touch raw coordinates:
                initialTouchRawX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchRawY = event.getRawY();
                //get current scaling of box
                currentScale = mTouchBox.getScaleX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist2 = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist2 > 10f) {
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float xmin = x_0 - viewWidth/2*(currentScale-1);
                float xmax = x_0 + viewWidth + viewWidth/2*(currentScale-1);
                float ymin = y_0 - viewHeight/2*(currentScale-1) + viewShift;
                float ymax = y_0 + viewHeight + viewHeight/2*(currentScale-1) + viewShift;
                //for dragging, check if touch is inside box bounds
                if (mode == DRAG 
                    && initialTouchRawX >= xmin && initialTouchRawX <= xmax 
                    && initialTouchRawY >= ymin && initialTouchRawY <= ymax ) { 
                    //we must shift the touch coordinates some:
                    float mShiftX = -(initialTouchRawX - x_0);
                    float mShiftY = -(initialTouchRawY - y_0);
                    mTouchBox.setX((float) event.getRawX()+mShiftX);
                    mTouchBox.setY((float) event.getRawY()+mShiftY);
                    mTouchBox2.setX((float) event.getRawX()+mShiftX);
                    mTouchBox2.setY((float) event.getRawY()+mShiftY); 
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist2 = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist2 > 10f) {
                        float newScale = newDist2 / oldDist2 * currentScale;
                        mTouchBox.setScaleX(newScale);
                        mTouchBox.setScaleY(newScale);                          
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            return true; 
        }
    });
```

This works fine, but I am wondering if there is a much easier and more efficient way to go about doing this. If I were to attach this code (with a few modifications) tot eh View Object I'm trying to drag and resize, then I get the out of bounds error if the pinch zoom gesture moves too quickly seemingly.

Ideally, I'd like to implement the pinchzoom/scale only when pinching over the object which needs to be scaled, but not necessarily perfectly in its bounds and to not have the app crash if one of the fingers goes out of bounds. Any suggestions on how to do that?